# How to install Java SE-20 in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java and I'm using Eclipse for the first time. I installed JDK 20 manually, but Eclipse didn't find it.

I've tried:
1- Installing Java SE-20 from the marketplace. JRE 20 is still unbound.
2- Using the search function
`(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin)`

and it says

`No JREs found in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin`

How would I solve this?

Comment: Similar: [*Why Eclipse 2018-12 says "No JREs found" in JDK-11?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54629793/642706)

Comment: Don't specify the bin folder, try pointing to the root folder (that contains the bin folder).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes When I pointed to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20" it gave me the same error message

Comment: Which search function? Please be more specific to describe the steps you are following.

Comment: @aled I click on Properties < Java Build Path < Libraries < Modulepath < Edit < Installed JREs < Search

Comment: Have you tried the solution suggested in the link that @BasilBourque shared?

Comment: I haven't, I will try and notify if it worked or not.  I mistook it for an automatic post as I'm pretty new to this website.

Comment: Yes, it worked. The solution was to use Properties < Java Build Path < Libraries < Modulepath < Edit < Installed JREs < Add and go to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20", thank you.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is it? One that was released when Java 20 was out?

Comment: Java 20 was released after the current Eclipse version 2023-03. So you need to install [Java 20 Support for Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-20-support-eclipse-2023-03-427) (in Eclipse via _Help > Eclipse Marketplace..._). Java 20 has no long time support (LTS), which means it will become obsolete with the Java 21 release in September. As Java beginner, better use the Java 17 that is shipped with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

howlger was right. You need to download the Java 20 Support for Eclipse 2023-03 through MarketPlace in Eclipse, install it and then restart Eclipse, once did that you only have to change the configuration once you are creating a new project.

1. Go to Help -> Eclipse MarketPlace
2. Search Java 20 Support for Eclipse 2023-03
3. Install
4. Let Eclipse Restart itself
5. Use create project to change the JavaSE and Java JDK
6. And you are ready to go